# Environment variables works on Django's server but not on Apache server

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, environment-variables

When I use the environment variable in Django's server, it works.

```
SMTP_PASSWORD = os.environ["SMTP_PASSWORD"]
```

However, when I run the same code on Apache, it doesn't. The code `os.environ["..."]` just doesn't work.

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.9.5 and Django 3.2.4.

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put environment variables in the apache config.

```
<VirtualHost hostname:443>
   ...
   SetEnv SMTP_PASSWORD smtp_password
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't want to put sensitive information in apache config you can still include your environment variable in your files, to read it when the server is starting or you can store those variables in your database.